# how do i resolve this [ discord.py ]

Tags: discord.py

how are you doing today i sure hope your doing great im sorry for the spam on other account i apologize. ok so my problem is that i switched from client to bot basically bot = commands.Bot i tried renaming all the commmands to bot.event or bot.command can someone pls help me pls i would appreciate it thank you here is the code :)

```
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong!\n`{round(client.latency*1000)}ms`')

@bot.command(aliases=['8ball'])
async def _8ball(ctx, *, question):
    responses = [   "It is certain.",
                    "As I see it, yes",
                    "Ask again later.",
                    "Better not tell you now.",
                    "Cannot predict now.",
                    "Concentrate and ask again.",
                    "Don't count it",
                    "It is certain.",
                    "It is decidedly so.", 
                    "Most likely.",
                    "My reply is no."
                    "My sources say no.",
                    "Outlook not so good.",
                    "Outlook good.",
                    "Reply hazy, try again.",
                    "Signs point to yes.",
                    "Very doubtful.",
                    "Without a doubt.",
                    "Yes.",
                    "Yes – definitely.",
                    "You may rely on it." ]
    await ctx.send(f'Question: {question}\nAnswer: {random.choice(responses)}')


@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
@bot.command()
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason="No reason provided"):
        await user.ban(reason=reason)
        kick = discord.Embed(title=f":boom: Kicked {user.name}!", description=f"Reason: {reason}\nBy: {ctx.author.mention}")
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=kick)
        await user.send(embed=kick)

@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
@bot.command()
async def ban(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason="No reason provided"):
        await user.ban(reason=reason)
        ban = discord.Embed(title=f":boom: Banned {user.name}!", description=f"Reason: {reason}\nBy: {ctx.author.mention}")
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=ban)
        await user.send(embed=ban)

@bot.command()
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
    
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')
    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user
        
        if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            await ctx.channel.send(f"Unbanned: {user.mention}")

@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def mute(ctx, user_id, userName: discord.User):
    if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.administrator:
        user = ctx.message.author
        role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="Muted")

@bot.command()
async def serverinfo(ctx):
  name = str(ctx.guild.name)
  description = str(ctx.guild.description)

  owner = str(ctx.guild.owner)
  id = str(ctx.guild.id)
  region = str(ctx.guild.region)
  memberCount = str(ctx.guild.member_count)

  icon = str(ctx.guild.icon_url)
   
  embed = discord.Embed(
      title=name + " Server Information",
      description=description,
      color=discord.Color.blue()
    )
  embed.set_thumbnail(url=icon)
  embed.add_field(name="Owner", value=owner, inline=True)
  embed.add_field(name="Server ID", value=id, inline=True)
  embed.add_field(name="Region", value=region, inline=True)
  embed.add_field(name="Member Count", value=memberCount, inline=True)

  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  await client.add_roles(user, role)

@bot.command()
async def setdelay(ctx, seconds: int):
    await ctx.channel.edit(slowmode_delay=seconds)
    await ctx.send(f"Set the slowmode delay in this channel to {seconds} seconds!")

@bot.command()
async def afk(ctx, mins):
    current_nick = ctx.author.nick
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} has gone afk for {mins} minutes.")
    await ctx.author.edit(nick=f"{ctx.author.name} [AFK]")

    counter = 0
    while counter <= int(mins):
        counter += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(60)

        if counter == int(mins):
            await ctx.author.edit(nick=current_nick)
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} is no longer AFK")
            break

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Afk(bot))

def user_is_me(ctx):
    return ctx.message.author.id == "Your ID" 



def convert(time):
  pos = ["s","m","h","d"]

  time_dict = {"s" : 1, "m" : 60, "h" : 3600, "d": 3600*24}

  unit = time[-1]

  if unit not in pos:
    return -1
  try:
    val = int(time[:-1])
  except:
    return -2

  return val * time_dict[unit]

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def giveaway(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Let's start with this giveaway! Answer these questions within 15 seconds!")

  questions = ["Which channel should it be hosted in?", "What should be the duration of the giveaway? (s|m|h|d)", "What is the prize of the giveaway?"]

  answers = []

  def check(m):
    return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

  for i in questions:
    await ctx.send(i)

    try:
      msg = await bot.wait_for('messsage', timeout=15.0, check=check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
      await ctx.send('You didn\'t answer in time, please be quicker next time!')
      return
    else: 
      answers.append(msg.content)

  try:
    c_id = int(answers[0][2:-1])
  except:
    await ctx.send(f"You didn't mention a channel properly. Do it like this {ctx.channel.mention} next time.")
    return

  channel = bot.get_channel(c_id)

  time = convert(answers[1])
  if time == -1:
    await ctx.send(f"You didn't answer with a proper unit. Use (s|m|h|d) next time!")
    return
  elif time == -2:
    await ctx.send(f"The time just be an integer. Please enter an integer next time.")
    return
  
  prize = answers[2]

  await ctx.send(f"The giveaway will be in {channel.mention} and will last {answers[1]} seconds!")

  embed = discord.embed(title = "Giveaway!", description = f"{prize}", color = ctx.author.color)

  embed.add_field(name = "Hosted by:", value = ctx.author.mention)

  embed.set_footer(text = f"Ends {answers[1]} from now!")

  my_msg = await channel.send(embed = embed)

  await my_msg.add_reaction("")

  await asyncio.sleep(time)

  new_msg = await channel.fetch_message(my_msg.id)

  users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
  users.pop(users.index(bot.user))

  winner = random.choice(users)

  await channel.send(f"Congratulations! {winner.mention} won the prize: {prize}!")


@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def reroll(ctx, channel : discord.TextChannel, id_ : int):
  try:
    new_msg = await channel.fetch_message(id_)
  except:
    await ctx.send("The ID that was entered was incorrect, make sure you have entered the correct giveaway message ID.")
  users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
  users.pop(users.index(bot.user))

  winner = random.choice(users)

  await channel.send(f"Congratulations the new winner is: {winner.mention} for the giveaway rerolled!")
```

if you want me to answer anything to help you solve it feel free to comment thank you so much have a great day!

Comment: Instead of creating a new account simply wait till someone answers the previous question, though this question is still of really poor quality.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you copied most of the code from the internet and bashed it together to create a bot or a cog (based on your question I would guess a bot).

Assuming this is a snippet of your main bot file and not a cog there are a couple of things that could be different:

1. Put your utility functions in one place (peferably after your import statatements). It's good practise overall and makes more readeable code.
2. Unless you have a cog class in the same file as your bot instance (which is bad practise) you shouldn't need this:

```
def setup(bot):
        bot.add_cog(Afk(bot))
```

If there is a cog class named Afk you should move it into a separate file (putting the cog class into the main bot file defeats the purpose of the cog)

3. In your mute command you have `pass_context = True`. This is from the old version of discord.py and is no longer needed.

I can't tell you much more since there's no point in trying to debug your code since you didn't give us any errors or stacktrace to work with.

Answer (score 0):

It is very exhausting, so you can just leave `client` in every command, just write this `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'your prefix')` it is the same bot, but it just has a different name.
If you meant that, because i didn't really understand what you need